# Constructing a 201 body in Tornado when collection and item handlers are separate

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, tornado

In my Tornado RESTful API, I have a `CollectionHandler` at `/{prefix}/items/` with a `post()` to create a new `item` that will be placed under `/items/{id}`. When I return the `201` status code, I want to include the body of that `/items/{id}`, as constructed by `ItemHandler`'s `get()`, while not duplicating its logic. This resulted in a static method with lots of parameters:

```
class CollectionHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.service = Service()

    def post(self, prefix):
        do_stuff(prefix)
        item, item_url = create_item()
        self.set_status(201)
        self.set_header('Location', item_url)
        self.write(ItemHandler.do_get(self.service, item_url, item.id))

class ItemHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.service = Service()

    @staticmethod
    def do_get(service, item_url, item_id):
        item = service.get_item(item_id)
        if not item: raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)
        response = construct_response(item_url, item)
        return response

    def get(self, item_id):
        item_url = get_url(self.request)
        self.write(ItemHandler.do_get(self.service, item_url, item_id))
```

How can I clean this up? I was thinking of internally doing an HTTP request for the newly created `/items/{id}` and including the response, but there must be some better way - it might not even work because of blocking...

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly I'd suggest you consider a redirect in your CollectionHandler post()

```
self.redirect('/items/' + str(item.id))
```

However I guess you are attached to your 201 status code so a redirect wont work for you.

Have you tried using mixins like this?:

```
class MixIt():
    def __init__(self):
        self.service = Service()

    def do_get(item_url, item_id):
        item = self.service.get_item(item_id)
        if not item: raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)
        response = construct_response(item_url, item)
        return response

class CollectionHandler(MixIt, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, prefix):
        do_stuff(prefix)
        item, item_url = create_item()
        self.set_status(201)
        self.set_header('Location', item_url)
        self.write(self.do_get(item_url, item.id))

class ItemHandler(MixIt, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, item_id):
        item_url = get_url(self.request)
        self.write(self.do_get(item_url, item_id))
```